# Return null values if parameter is null, else return specific values of a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a stored proc where if the value of my input parameter is Null, i have to return null values in the 'Color' column, if the input parameter is, say, 'Blue' ,I have to return  the 'Color' column where the values are 'Blue'. This is my sql code:

```
Create Proc Reports.GetProductsByColor @Color nvarchar(20)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
BEGIN
Select SalesLT.Product.ProductID as ProductID,
       SalesLT.Product.Name as 'Name',
       SalesLT.Product.ListPrice as Price,
       SalesLT.Product.Color as Color,
       SalesLT.Product.Size as Size
From   SalesLT.Product
Where  Color = CASE WHEN @Color is NULL
               THEN NULL
               ELSE @Color
               END
END
GO
Exec Reports.GetProductsByColor 'Blue'
GO
Exec Reports.GetProductsByColor NULL
GO
```

`Exec Reports.GetProductsByColor 'Blue'` works perfectly fine and displays only the 'Blue' values. However, for `Exec Reports.GetProductsByColor NULL`, I do not get any result set even though there are 50 NULL values in the 'Color' column. What am I doing wrong here? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `null = null` returns `false` that does not work. Use

```
Where (@Color is NULL and Color is null)
   or (@color = color)
```

Comment: @PinkPrint if an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
where ISNULL(Color,'-') =IsNUll(@Color,'-')
```

Note that the following WHERE clause is not SARG and will not use associtaed index with Color column, if available.

To solve the SARG issue, you will need to use the [@juergen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48484861/1666800)

Comment: @juergend Yes, I have mentioned this performance problem in my answer and that is why I have referenced to your answer for performance improvement

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Proc GetProductsByColor @Color nvarchar(20)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
BEGIN
    if(@color is null)
       Select  SalesLT.Product.ProductID as ProductID,
               SalesLT.Product.Name as 'Name',
               SalesLT.Product.ListPrice as Price,
               SalesLT.Product.Color as Color,
               SalesLT.Product.Size as Size
        From   SalesLT.Product
        Where  Color is NULL
    else 
        Select SalesLT.Product.ProductID as ProductID,
               SalesLT.Product.Name as 'Name',
               SalesLT.Product.ListPrice as Price,
               SalesLT.Product.Color as Color,
               SalesLT.Product.Size as Size
        From   SalesLT.Product
        Where  Color = @Color
END
GO
Exec GetProductsByColor 'Blue'
GO
Exec GetProductsByColor NULL
GO
```